# How can I capitalize a letter from a word one at a time, then add each instance of the word with a caps letter into a array?

Tags: ruby

My code:

```
def wave(str)
  ary = []
  increase_num = 0
  str = str.chars
  until increase_num > str.size
   ary << str[increase_num].upcase && increase_num += 1
  end
end
```

What it's supposed to do:

```
wave("hello") => ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]
```

I would really appreciate some help, as you probably know by looking at it I'm relatively new.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str = "hello"
```

```
str.size.times.map { |i| str[0,i] << str[i].upcase << str[i+1..] }
  #=> ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]
```

Comment: Or similarly (but with a possibly dubious use of `#tap`): `word = word.downcase; word.length.times.map { |i| word.dup.tap { |w| w[i] = w[i].upcase } }`.

Comment: @muistooshort, thanks. To me, `tap` is fine but `dup` knocks off points for elegance.

Comment: Hello Cary! you might want to downcase `str`. Otherwise the wave doesn't look like a wave for `'HELLO'`.

Comment: @muistooshort `Array.new(str.size) {str.downcase}.each_with_index {|s,idx| s[idx] = s[idx].upcase }`

Comment: @EricDuminil, can we assume a downcased string is passed or that the ith character is to be upcased if it is not already in upper case? Downcasing would uglify my answer.

Comment: @engineersmnky, nice! That warrants a separate answer.

Comment: @engineersmnky Clever use of the oft-forgotten `Array.new`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `Kernel#then` beautifies so many things e.g. `str.downcase.then {|str| str.size.times.map { |i| str[0,i] << str[i].upcase << str[i+1..] }}`

Answer (score 3):

I would go about it as follows:

```
def wave(str)
  str = str.downcase # so we can ensure a wave even if the original string had capitalization
  str.each_char.with_index.map do |c,idx|
    str[0...idx].concat(c.upcase,str[idx.+(1)..-1])
  end
end
wave("hello")
#=> ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]
```

- `str.each_char.with_index.map do |c,idx|` - This converts the `String` into an `Enumerator` and yields each character and its index to the `map` block.
- `str[0...idx]` - In the block we slice the string into characters 0 through index (exclusive)
- `.concat(c.upcase,str[idx.+(1)..-1])` - Then we concatenate that with the current character upcased and the remaining portion of the `String` (index + 1 through the end of the `String`)

First 2 passes will look like:

```
  # idx = 0 
  # c = "h" 
  # str[0...idx].concat(c.upcase,str[idx.+(1)..-1])
  "".concat("H","ello")
  # idx = 1 
  # c = "e" 
  # str[0...idx].concat(c.upcase,str[idx.+(1)..-1])
  "h".concat("E","llo")
```